# ksoap2 v prefixo to any other prefix

Tags: java, soap, ksoap2, prefix

Hi i have a code for generating a simple request to a example soap server where i need to build a request like:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"  xmlns:ns="http://10.1.5.80:8080/">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <ns:GETSERVERTIME/>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

but i get

```
<v:Envelope 
    xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/1999/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:d="http://www.w3.org/1999/XMLSchema" 
    xmlns:c="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" 
    xmlns:v="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<v:Header />
    <v:Body>
        <n0:GETSERVERTIME xmlns:n0="http://localhost:8080/" />
    </v:Body>
</v:Envelope>
```

i Only need to change "v:" to "soapenv:"

my code:

```
/**
 * Created by Vinicius Gati on 30/12/14.
 *
 */
public class ServerSOAP {

    private static final String METHOD_NAME = "GETSERVERTIME";
    private static final String NAMESPACE = "http://localhost:8080/";
    private static final String SOAP_ACTION = "";
    private static final String URL = "http://10.1.5.80:8080/ws/SERVERTIME.apw?WSDL";

    public static String getServerTime() {
        String retorno = "";

        SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);

        SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER10);
        envelope.implicitTypes = false;
        envelope.setAddAdornments(false);

        envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
        HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
        androidHttpTransport.debug = true;

        try {
            androidHttpTransport.call( NAMESPACE + METHOD_NAME, envelope );
            SoapObject response = (SoapObject) envelope.getResponse();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return retorno;
    }

}
```

but i'm crazy trying this, no success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As You may see in:
https://github.com/mosabua/ksoap2-android/blob/master/ksoap2-base/src/main/java/org/ksoap2/SoapEnvelope.java

writing method defines prefixes as string constants (code copy from class SoapEnvelope, see provided link):

```
public void write(XmlSerializer writer) throws IOException {
    writer.setPrefix("i", xsi);
    writer.setPrefix("d", xsd);
    writer.setPrefix("c", enc);
    writer.setPrefix("v", env);
    writer.startTag(env, "Envelope");
    writer.startTag(env, "Header");
    writeHeader(writer);
    writer.endTag(env, "Header");
    writer.startTag(env, "Body");
    writeBody(writer);
    writer.endTag(env, "Body");
    writer.endTag(env, "Envelope");
}
```

So, You may try to define own class, inheriting from SoapSerializationEnvelope and experiment with redefining this method to use "soapenv" prefix.

BTW: if WS cant read prefix of any name, its a poor code on this service side. "soapenv" or "v" should be interpreted as identical in both xml's You included.

Marcin

Comment: yeah i know that this should work, but sadly the SOAP protocol from the ERP we use do not work with v prefix... i spent hours to discover that... thanks i will try the solution.

Answer (score 1):

Dude,

I've solved this issue. Actually I've extend the `SoapSerializationEnvelope` class and overridden the `SoapSerializationEnvelope`'s `write()` method as follows

```
@Override
public void write(XmlSerializer writer) throws IOException {
    Log.d("DEBUG", "XML create process started");
    env = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/";
    String tem = "http://tempuri.org/";
    String ner = "http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/MYSERVICE";
    //writer.text("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>");  
    // Don't try like above,  it will cause errors, for instead of this, you    should use below code
    writer.startDocument("UTF-8", true);
    writer.setPrefix("soapenv", env); //these are propably same for you 
    writer.setPrefix("tem", tem); //these are propably same for you 
    writer.setPrefix("ner", ner); // but this must change with your namespace   writer.setPrefix("myTag", ner);   
    writer.startTag(env, "Envelope");
    writer.startTag(env, "Header");
    writeHeader(writer);
    writer.endTag(env, "Header");
    writer.startTag(env, "Body");
    writer.startTag(tem, "Method");
    writer.startTag(tem, "inputObject");
    writer.startTag(ner, "property");
    writer.text("property value");
    writer.endTag(ner, "property");  
    writeBody(writer);
    writer.endTag(tem, "inputObject");
    writer.endTag(tem, "Method");
    writer.endTag(env, "Body");
    writer.endTag(env, "Envelope");
    writer.endDocument();
    Log.d("DEBUG","XML created");
}
```